# It is possible to program Facebook chat client?

Tags: facebook, sdk, chat

I have a chat client on Facebook chat. It works, but my login is over Facebook username and password. I need to login over facebook SDK, email and password. It is possible to program it? Will it be possible even in April 2015 when the chat API gets turned off? Do you have any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to program it?

No. API Logins need to be initiated manually by the user that is how OAuth works on Facebook.

> Will it be possible even in April 2015 when the chat API gets turned off?

No, if XMPP gets disabled then obviously it will not work.

> Do you have any working solution?

No.